# Unity 3d How to make an instance of the scene receive an object-oriented script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instance

Ok guys, I have a question.
I'm doing a simple object-oriented world generation script.

My question is quite simple, void Start_Terrain () How do I get a gameobject to get this instance of terrain read-only.

```
void Start()
{     
    Start_Terrain();     
    DbItems.CreateItems();     
}

void Start_Terrain()
{
    LevelGenerator currentLevel = new LevelGenerator(
        "Default",
        0,
        123,
        false,
        100,
        100,
        0.07f
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your question a bit more .. Maybe it's only me but I really have no clue what you are asking ...

Comment: I need to instantiate a gameobject in the scene, add the Level Generator script and add those arguments mentioned above.

Comment: create a preloader to the scene and there set the script with `DontDestroyOnLoad()` that way when the next scene loads your values are set is that what your looking for?